# Failed to enroll admin, error:%o message=Calling enroll endpoint failed, CONNECTION Timeout

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am running my fabric network on kubernetes and I have setup ca servers for all the organisations. I am able to register and enroll the user from the cli but when i am using the **fabric-ca-client** library with **nodejs** to register and enroll the users. I am facing the CONNECTION Timeout issue, also at the same time if I look at the logs of my ca-server it show that is able to process the request.
Edit1: I am using the same code provided in fabric-sample to register and enroll the users.

All the all the pods are communicating with each other using these services in kubernetes

this is how my connection profile looks

```
"certificateAuthorities": {
    "ca-org2": {
        "url": "https://ca-org2:8054",
        "caName": "ca-org2",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "pem": ["-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nmkNo0YfKuX4CICodtpp6AKtNWXreskaN+kRMH8eDmwvxkhvTK68ejv8U\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"]
        },
        "httpOptions": {
            "verify": false
        }
    }
}
```

[image: nodejs application logs]

[image: ca server logs]

Comment: What is the URL you re using to connect to the server? Is this server accessible from the device you are trying to run the provisioning on? Seems like some firewall is dropping the connection, or the address is not setup correctly.

Comment: yes, requests from nodejs app  is passing successfully to the CA server. Since all the components are running within the kubernetes cluster, i am using services to access my deployment/pods

Comment: Your CA logs are normal. Are you sure these logs are appended when you call the register function?

Comment: yes, we can verify it using the logs timestamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue. The issue was related to the connection timeout, my CA Server was receving the requests and able to process them also but due to the short timeout the request was being cancelled. The solution was to increase the `connection timeout` and `request-timeout`. The default value of timeouts is 3s and I increased it to 30s and it started working. The default configuration can be found [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/main/fabric-ca-client/config/default.json)

```
{
    "request-timeout" : 3000,
    "tcert-batch-size" : 10,
    "crypto-hash-algo": "SHA2",
    "crypto-keysize": 256,
    "crypto-hsm": false,
    "connection-timeout": 3000
}
```

we can update the timeout values from source code of the fabric-ca-client library or simply can use the methods of `fabric-common` library to update the these configuration values like this.

```
const { Utils: utils } = require('fabric-common');
const path=require('path');
let config=utils.getConfig()
config.file(path.resolve(__dirname,'config.json'))
```

And here is our modified configuration file `config.json`

```
  {
  "request-timeout" : 30000,
  "tcert-batch-size" : 10,
  "crypto-hash-algo": "SHA2",
  "crypto-keysize": 256,
  "crypto-hsm": false,
  "connection-timeout": 30000
  }
```